# Mac OSX MySQL - Permission denied

Tags: mysql, macos

I installed MySQL server a few hours before. While the installation, the installer told me a password. I copied it to clipboard to change it. After that I wanted to connect with MySQL Workbench. It didn´t worked and the program crashed. I restarted the macbook but forgot to save the password. I reinstalled the service but it didn´t told me the password again. If I want to connect to the server, Workbench tells me: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" but I dont use a password in this configuration. Can you help me?

Comment: try from terminam $mysql -uroot -h localhost or $mysql -uroot -h 127.0.0.1 . if you want that you give a password use the -p option. You can also reinstall the database tables use #mysql_install_db -umysql

Comment: -bash: -uroot: command not found

Comment: Dont type the $ at the start of the line

Comment: Still command not found :S